# Curl failing in Kubernetes pod

Tags: http, curl, kubernetes

Having an issue with a pod post k8s upgrade on cluster. The pod wont come up cos its stuck trying to complete the init container

The init container does a curl against another pod and greps for a specific HTTP response

```
Command:
   sh
   -c
   while true; do
    echo "Waiting for prosody to become available..."
    sleep 1
    curl -s -i -k https://wad-0-mum-prosody:5281/xmpp-websocket/ | grep -q "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
    [ $? -ne 0 ] || break
   done
```

The pod which it does the curl against is up and running and is accepting on port 5281. When I run the curl manually with grep and I get below

```html
/ $ curl -s -i -k https://wad-0-mum-prosody:5281/xmpp-websocket/ | grep -q "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" / $ echo $? 1
```

I didn't have this issue in the other clusters I upgraded recently so I am stumped.

Comment: How the url 'https://wad-0-mum-prosody:5281/xmpp-websocket' is setup ? if using Ingress then can you also share the same ?
Also can try service name(or service port) directly instead of this URL ?  
Also can you try with the pod IP and pod port ?

Comment: so its got a service in front of it and the endpoint is registering correctly

below from a describe on the service
TargetPort:    5281/TCP
Endpoints:     100.96.2.23:5281

below is the pod 

wad-0-mum-prosody-5db9c7b568-4zv8m              2/2   Running      0     7m4s  100.96.2.23

Comment: @DeirdreRodgers Was the image used for curl in init container and test the same? There might be different versions of `curl` and slightly different output. I'd try to remove `grep`, add `-v` for verbosity and check init container logs. This way you can rule out `curl` and loop syntax and continue digging into setup on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the initContainer here is supposed to be waiting for other Pod to come online. When it is UP, initContainer's job is done.
Could you please try this code in your spec. It is doing the same thing, just in a different fashion.

```
initContainers:
      - name: init-container-name
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'while [ `curl -Lk --write-out "%{http_code}\n" --silent --output /dev/null "https://wad-0-mum-prosody:5281/xmpp-websocket"` -ne 200 ]; do sleep 2; done']
```